# How to get exactly duration from CallLog in Milliseconds

Tags: android, duration, calllog

How I can find out the exactly call duration in milliseconds from my CallLog?

I get only rounded numbers.

```
    Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
    Cursor c = getActivity().getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(allCalls, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        int type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));// for call type, Incoming or out going

        if (type == 2){
            long duration = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
        }
    }
    c.close();
```

Comment: and what `CallLog.Calls.DURATION` documentation says?

Comment: that it give me the seconds but he is rounding the seconds up by me, i need it exactly without round up

Comment: huh? you can't get the call's duration in milis it is stored as seconds ...

Comment: ok :/ i found my issue it was by me i calculated it wrong, i calculated the minutes and not the seconds thats now very embarrassing